# How to properly arrange the processing resources of a pipeline in GATE Developer?

Tags: nlp, gate

The arrangement of the processing resources in [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) pipeline may be critical for successful annotation. Therefore I was wondering how to properly arrange the processing resources of a pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GATE PR's should be arranged according to a logical way. Usually it looks like:

a) Cleanup previously created annotations (Annotation Set Reset PR)

b) Tokenize Text (Tokenizer PR)

c) Split text to sentences (Sentence Splitter PR).

e) Assign POS Tags (POS Tagger PR)
and etc...

If you load a default ANNIE application from GATE Developer (File->Ready Made Applications ->ANNIE->Double click on "ANNIE" under "Application" node on left part of GATE Developer) you will see a typical pipeline PRs sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can arrange the GATE PR like this , If you want Create a **GAPP** file and you want to Process it over a document then

1. Document Reset PR

2.Annie English Tokenizer

3.Annie Gazetteer (if you have)

4.Annie sentence Spilter

5.Annie POS Tagger

So, There are the basics  steps .
If you have Ontology , Then you can create a separate application **RootFinder** ,

In that You can give English , Pos tagger , Morphological Analyaser .

After that In first application After Pos Tagger

6. `OntoRootGazetter` , there you can give ontology and the rootFinder application.

7 .Then use flexible Gazetteer and as a runtime Parameter add , 'Token.Root' .So, In this way you can create a new Pipeline.